# Find out target platform of build?

Tags: scons

How do I find out what platform SCons is building for (Linux, Mac OS X, Windows, &c-- not concerned with architecture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will  http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.platform (true,true)
do what you want?  If not you may have to map it yourself from data in the other
platform methods.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `env['PLATFORM']` once you've created an Environment.  I think it comes from sys.platform.

Comment: Not super useful with the default environment, since it just says "posix".

Answer (score 0):

Scons has a builtin function `Platform()` that you can call before you create your Environment.  Probably preferable to use `Platform()` than Python's `platform.platform(true, true)` (you don't have to import platform into you SConstruct, for example.)  After you've created your environment you should use `env['PLATFORM']` as suggested by @GaryO.

Comment: The `Platform` function is used to **set** the platform, not retrieve it. It cannot be considered to be preferable over `platform.platform` since they're not doing the same thing.